# Android app link only works from adb

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my app to be launched when a link with a specific, custom scheme is clicked on.
But it only works from adb with:

`./adb shell a start -a Android.Intent.Action.VIEW -d "ghd://whateversite.com"`

It doesn't work when a link is clicked, or the URL is written directly in the browser.

I'm using:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".link.LaunchActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="ghd" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: So how did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:host` too in the Intent filter

```
<activity
    android:name=".link.LaunchActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="ghd" android:host="whateversite.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But "whateversite.com" can be, actually, whateversite :) the only part that will always be there is the scheme ghd.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `autoVerify=true` from your `<intent-filter/>`. As said in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#config-verify) :

> When the android:autoVerify attribute is present, installing your app causes the system to attempt to verify all hosts associated with the web URIs in all of your app's intent filters. The system treats your app as the default handler for the specified URI pattern only if it successfully verifies all app link patterns declared in your manifest.

Since you didn't add any host, this might be why it is not working.

Comment: You're right it didn't make sense. I removed it but the behaviour is the same. Thanks!

Comment: That's weird because I now have the exact same thing on my side, and it just works... Also on your example you are using the "mdw" scheme and your adb command is using "ghd", but I don't think that's the issue here, I might be a misprint.

Comment: It was :P so in your case it just works when you write it directly in the browser?

Comment: I only tried to open a link with this scheme. I never tried opening the link directly by typing it on the browser's status bar. Maybe you should try to create a page with symply a link referencing this scheme